# Laravel 5 How to solve the error when validate a unique username using Boostrap FormValidation Remote

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3

I got an error when i want to validate an unique username using Boostrap FormValidation remote.

Below are the error that i received in the browser console:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Uncaught TypeError: b.success is not a function

Below are my code

```
$('#user_form').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Username is required'
                    },
                    remote: {
                        message: 'This Username has already been taken',
                        url: '/check_unique',
                        data: {
                            type: 'username'
                        },
                        type: 'POST'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Web.php

```
Route::post('/check_unique', 'UserController@unique');
```

Controller

```
public function unique()
{
    $user= User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->count();

    if($user> 0) {
        $isAvailable = FALSE;
    } else {
        $isAvailable = TRUE;
    }

    echo json_encode(
            array(
                'valid' => $isAvailable
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a standard way to do it in Laravel 5 ( see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation and [Laravel 5: Best way to validate form with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762376/laravel-5-best-way-to-validate-form-with-javascript#29099790) )

If you want to do it your way, then :

- The `XMLHttpRequest` is due to Bootstrap or jQuery, nothing we can to for that
- `Uncaught TypeError: b.success is not a function` mean that :

  - Maybe your request just didn't append ? look at your php logs
  - Does { success: $isUnique } work ?

During my googling of your method I didn't find anything, and got the links I gave you.

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you please give more explaination, and how do i test whether { success: $isUnique } work? i found a link which is similiar to my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823662/why-formvalidation-plugin-throws-me-a-bug-in-remote-validation